# Collect last 7 days data from SQL and group by days

Tags: mysql, sql

how can I count last 7 days data from SQL and group them by day/date (excluding today).
I should be able to use the result as `$resultday1`, `$resultday2`, `$resultday3` etc.
If there was 10 total SQL entries in day 1 (yesterday) `$resultday1` should show "10".
and the days should be last 7 only, and today/current day should not consider.
The following PHP SQL script shows the total count only

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM orders WHERE username='jondoe'
```

database is a list of referrals made by a registered user in previous days.
a single table contains all user's referral details, table name "orders" as per above example.

Comment: Please edit the question with the database that you are using.

Comment: @Popeye, there is not much about database, I just want to filter the table results based on username and group by last 7 days.

Comment: Finding last 7 days are different in different database. In oracle, you can directly use date - 7. In other database you need to use datediff. So please share the name of tbe database also.

Comment: @Popeye, oh, ok. It is MySQL,

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact query as you want

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*), DATE(order_date) order_date
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    order_date < CURDATE()
        AND order_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY order_date
ORDER BY order_date DESC;
```

Comment: Just replace your date column with order_date in query.

Comment: thanks for the code. Could you please also add how can I echo each count in PHP ? like $resultday1 and $resultday2